# setting the max height of an image to the browser windows height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is a repost because i couldn't comment on answers from my earlier question since i made the question while not signed in.

i'm trying to prevent an image from ever becoming taller than the browser window so that the viewer never has to scroll down to see the rest of the image.

however, i can't figure out how to set the max height of the image to the browser windows height.

so far i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>TEST TITLE</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>

<body>

<div class="container">
        <img src="dovelow.jpg" alt="Dove">

</div><!-- .container -->

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried ?
You will need simple javascript to change width and height style atttributes of the image.

Comment: You can only set %'s in relation to the parent. If the parent (.container) is not 100% of the window, then you'll need to use javascript.

Comment: would it be possible to see an example in jsfiddle? i'm having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: put image as background image and then use "background-size: cover;". here are examples: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Or` add a class to the image: [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzExs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzExs/)

Because its using `jquery` is should be cross browser

Answer (score 0):

the better way is that, change `width` to lower than `100%` like `87%`

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing is, I've been looking for the same thing. On my website, I used to use `max-height: 75%;` to keep the images from getting too big, but today, I just noticed, it stopped working. It probably stopped working weeks, or maybe even months ago. So that was disappointing. I'll assume it had something to do with a recent Chrome update, or possibly something WordPress stopped doing.

You know, it's possible my code never worked. I just thought it did.

Anyway, I was searching around for a solution and got quite discouraged... until I found this little gem:

http://stanhub.com/how-to-make-div-element-100-height-of-browser-window-using-css-only/

Turns out the bit of CSS you need involves using the units called `vh` for 'viewport height,' or `vw` for 'viewport width.' So in my case, it's `max-height: 75vh;`, if you want to keep the images from being taller than 75% of the browser window.

So whatever you're planning, this should certainly help.